# Making Object using JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to access object data after JSON.stringify. I'm getting undefined with console.log(data[0].colour)

```
let data = [];
let colours = ['#340068' , '#ff6978' , '#fffcf9' , '#b1ede8' , '#6d435a']
let names = ['coffee' , 'cake' , 'holiday' , 'break' , 'lunch']

var result = colours.map(function(element , i){
  data.push(`{'colour' : '${element}','name' : '${names[i]}'}`)
})
```

Thanks in advance

```
JSON.stringify(data)

console.log(data[0].colour)
```

Comment: to make object you use JSON.parse

Comment: You should probably look up what [`JSON.stringiy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) does.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` converts objects into *strings*. If you want to convert some JSON into an object/array, use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: `stringify` returns string so you can not use array access notation on a text

Comment: Also both those methods return a value, so you need to assign it. Otherwise nothing is going to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First and Foremost*  single quotes

> '

represents character.... for string use double quotes

> "

**Secondly**
JSON stringify doesn't get objects...

JSON.PARSE on a valid JSON String makes the JSON object..

```js
let data = [];
let colours = ['#340068' , '#ff6978' , '#fffcf9' , '#b1ede8' , '#6d435a']
let names = ['coffee' , 'cake' , 'holiday' , 'break' , 'lunch']

var result = colours.map(function(element , i){
var item = `{"colour" : "${element}","name" : "${names[i]}"}`;
var itemstr = JSON.stringify(item);  
var itemObj = JSON.parse(itemstr);
 data.push(itemObj) //replaced '
})
   
var FirstItemOBj = JSON.parse(data[0]);
console.log(FirstItemOBj.colour);  //  gets the first object of strings
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So do I always need to use JSON.parse to access the object? I cant just use data.colour[0] for example?

Comment: You can only use [O].colour on a json object... What you are doing is on a string ....  If you don't want to use JSON.parse every now & then ....structure your application with objects... I will update this answer tomorrow morning

Comment: I think i have understood what I needed was the following:

Comment: colours.map(function(element , i){
var item = JSON.parse(`{"colour" : "${element}","name" : "${names[i]}"}`);
 data.push(item) 
})

Comment: or refactored even further colours.map(function(item,i){
  data.push(JSON.parse(`{"colour" : "${item}","name" : "${names[i]}"}`))
})